# populating a div when a value is entered in a text field using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i want when a value(membership_number) is entered in a text field then it checks to the database for the corresponding name and display on the div....
this is what i have done so far..

**my jquery code**

```
$(function(){
    var dis=$('#full');

    $('#membership_number').change(function(e){

        var sel=$(this).val();
        dis.html('');
        if(sel!='0'){
            $.get('get_leader.php',{sel:sel},function(data){

                    dis.html(data);

                    });
            }

        }).change();




    });
```

**my php code**

```
 if(isset($_GET['sel'])){
$membership_num=$_GET['sel'];

    if(!empty($dregion)){
$search=mysql_query("SELECT fname,mname,lname from members where       

  membership_number='$membership_num'") 
   or die("Error occured in selecting a table");


    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($search)){
                $fname=ucfirst($rows['fname']);
                $lname=ucfirst($rows['lname']);
                $mname=ucfirst(substr($rows['mname'],0,1));
                $full=$fname.'.'.$mname.'.'.$lname;
                echo $full;



        }



    }
      }
```

**my html code**

```
  <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="id_password">Membership Number</label>
                    <div class="controls">
       <input name="membership_number" maxlength="100" 
             placeholder="Enter membership Number ..." type="text" 
              class="input-large" id="membership_number" />
                    </div>
                </div> 


   <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="id_password">Full Name</label>
                    <div class="controls" id='full'>
                    //display data here...
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: is it working? whats the problem

Comment: it is not working, i want when user enters a membership number it checks to the database and display the name in the div

Comment: your jquery seems fine, if its not working then your server side code is the problem, ideally you should include the code for that as well.

Comment: can you log the data in console or alert and check if you are getting it right ?

Comment: i hav included my php file and html codes nw @Relfor

Comment: i checked in console but there is no error displayed @mohkhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you have two html elements with the id="full".  Try using this for your php script (sorry your variable names were so horrible I changed them all):

2.php:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['member_num'])){
    $membership_num = $_GET['member_num'];
    echo $membership_num;
 } 
?>
```

js2.js

```
$(function(){

    $('#membership_number').change(function(e){
        var member_num = $(this).val();
        var results_elmt = $('#results');

        results_elmt.html('');

        if(member_num != '0'){
            $.get('2.php',{member_num: member_num},function(data){
              results_elmt.html(data);
            });
        }

    });
});
```

...and this for your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js2.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="membership_number">Membership Number</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input name="membership_number" maxlength="100" 
         placeholder="Enter membership Number ..." type="text" 
         class="input-large" id="membership_number" />
  </div>
</div> 


<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="full_name">Full Name</label>
  <input name="full_name" maxlength="100" 
         placeholder="Enter Full Name ..." type="text" 
         class="input-large" id="full_name" />

  <div class="controls" id="results">HELLO</div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Substitute in the proper paths to your js stuff in the `<script>` tags.

You also have to decide on a better indentation strategy.  Your code is a ridiculous mess.

And what is this for:

```
}).change();
```

Get rid of that.

Comment: Your welcome.  You should also upvote the other reply for suggesting things to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **console.log(data);** or **alert(data);** after $.get.

or you can use **firebug add-on** to check what parameter you are sending and result recieved.

Comment: i used alert(data)..it pop up nothing in it

Comment: Then your php script isn't returning anything.  Use something simple for you php script like I posted.  You should always test all your stuff without any db interaction--before adding the db stuff.